# JFrame - setting locations / borders?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to add a JButton, but it aligns horizontally with a progress bar.
How do I align the JButton on the line below?
Also, I'm trying to group all the components in separate groups, I'm not sure how to do this though. Does anyone know?

[image: Like this, I think this is from the Docs but I can't get it to work. Nothing is displayed.]

Comment: What IDE you are using??

Comment: Here is an example of using [combinations of layout managers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).

Answer (score 1):

For simple splitting of a `JFrame` you can use a `GridLayout` with 2 rows and 2 columns.

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,3,3)); //3,3 are gaps
frame.add(grid);
//add components here...
```

Comment: +1, I liked this idea, if I understood the question correctly :-) I can not see the image, since the `imgur` server is down on my side :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw the image is just some basic GUI components that the OP needs aligning - don't worry about it, not essential for understanding the question :)

Comment: Okay since you vouching for it, I am too satisfied now :-)